# How to measure the hardware space of the running ROS node?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to measure the complexity of my algorithm. The algorithm is developed to run in ROS node. How do we measure the space of the running ROS node taken?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221487/how-to-measure-the-hardware-space-of-the-running-ros-node?/) by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [htop](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/linux-htop-examples/) to monitor the CPU and memory usage of your processes.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1